Exploring the functionality of Intent.PutExtra and Intent.GetExtra generating Null
I have recently followed a Tutorial on Youtube by Philip Lackner(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A41hkHoYu4M) and built a basic Bluetooth app.I am looking to further the app
I am currently looking into using Intent filters to transfer information in a dual pane layout. The Intents seem to work but Im not sure, but I have noticed a few things that I would like help with.
Firstly I have a dual pane layout, I would like to send a Bluetooth device name through the fragment via the intent, but when I pull across the intent to the other side it generates a null.
I have tried all sorts of null checks, alterations and improvisations (I have got some very unique results) but I still have not got the Bluetooth name Im after and Im really wondering what I'm doing wrong.
Secondly, I have put a Log Statement in the intent PutExtra statement, the log is never sent to logcat or it seems even looked at, I believe this could be the problem but not sure how to solve it
I am using Hilt and Dagger, could this be part of the problem?
Here is my Main Activity
const val DEVICE_ID = "DEVICE_ID"
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            if (DEVICE_ID != null && !DEVICE_ID.isEmpty() && !DEVICE_ID.equals("null"))
    
    
                intent.let {
                //      val devices = it.getStringExtra(DEVICES)
                //      findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tt_conf_label)
                //          .text = getString(R.string.tt_confirmation_label, devices)
    
    
                    val transfer = intent.extras?.getString(DEVICE_ID)
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tt_conf_label)
                        .text = getString(R.string.tt_confirmation_label, transfer)
                    Log.d("test3 MA", "DEVICEID:"+ DEVICE_ID)
    
                }
            }
        }
    
package com.example.fragmentintro.presentation.components

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.fragmentintro.StyleFragment
import com.example.fragmentintro.exchange.BluetoothDevice
import com.example.fragmentintro.presentation.BluetoothUiState
import com.example.fragmentintro.presentation.MainActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import com.example.fragmentintro.R

const val DEVICE_ID = "DEVICE_ID"
@Composable
    fun DeviceScreen(
        state: BluetoothUiState,
        onStartScan: () -> Unit,
        onStopScan: () -> Unit
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            BluetoothDeviceList(
                pairedDevices = state.pairedDevices,
                scannedDevices = state.scannedDevices,
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
            )
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
            ) {

                Button(onClick = onStartScan) {
                    Text(text = "Start scan")
                }
                Button(onClick = onStopScan) {
                    Text(text = "Stop scan")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun BluetoothDeviceList(
        pairedDevices: List<BluetoothDevice>,
        scannedDevices: List<BluetoothDevice>,
        onClick: (BluetoothDevice) -> Unit,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = modifier
        ) {
            item {
                Text(
                    text = "Paired Devices",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
            items(pairedDevices) { device ->
                Text(
                    text = device.name ?: "(No name)",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clickable { onClick(device) }
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }

            item {
                Text(
                    text = "Scanned Devices",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
            items(scannedDevices) { device ->
                Text(
                    text = device.name ?: "(No name)",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clickable { onClick(device) }
                        .padding(16.dp))

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
                        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                            intent?.let {
                                val ttstatus = it.getStringExtra(DEVICE_ID)
                                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tt_conf_label).text =
                                    getString(R.string.tt_confirmation_label, ttstatus)

                                Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                                    .also { welcomeIntent ->
                                    
                                        welcomeIntent.putExtra(DEVICE_ID, ttstatus)

                                        startActivity(welcomeIntent)
                                    }
                    
    ```


This code is extremely difficult to read. You have Activity nested inside Fragment nested inside other classes. Also, you have a class DeviceScreen which is actually an Activity, then you have a class DeviceActivity which is not an Activity, but actually a Fragment. Names are useful and naming things badly isn't helpful.

Sorry about that, I agree and appreciate what you are saying, I was getting very stressed and moving things around a lot before I came to SO.I appreciate your feedback and will endeavour to clean up the code
